# Check properties that changed since last interval in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

In nodeJS, let's say that I have a little `setInterval`:

```js
setInterval(() => {
   // ...
}, 50)
```

And it sends to client entities:

```js
setInterval(() => {
   socket.emit("entities", { ... })
}, 50)
```

Entities looks like this:

```
{
  "0": {
    "collisionRadius": 40,
    "entityClass": "Prop",
    "health": 100,
    "maxHealth": 100,
    "model": "Tree",
    "position": {
      "x": 1970,
      "y": 1477
    },
    "uid": 0,
    "damage": 10,
    "dead": 0,
    "height": 32,
    "hits": [],
    "interpolatedYaw": 0,
    "slowed": 0,
    "stunned": 0,
    "timeDead": 0,
    "width": 32,
    "yaw": 0
  },
  "1": {
    "collisionRadius": 40,
    "entityClass": "Prop",
    "health": 100,
    "maxHealth": 100,
    "model": "Tree",
    "position": {
      "x": 1240,
      "y": 1866
    },
    "uid": 1,
    "damage": 10,
    "dead": 0,
    "height": 32,
    "hits": [],
    "interpolatedYaw": 0,
    "slowed": 0,
    "stunned": 0,
    "timeDead": 0,
    "width": 32,
    "yaw": 0
  },
  "2": {
    "collisionRadius": 40,
    "entityClass": "Prop",
    "health": 100,
    "maxHealth": 100,
    "model": "Tree",
    "position": {
      "x": 2195,
      "y": 2034
    },
    "uid": 2,
    "damage": 10,
    "dead": 0,
    "height": 32,
    "hits": [],
    "interpolatedYaw": 0,
    "slowed": 0,
    "stunned": 0,
    "timeDead": 0,
    "width": 32,
    "yaw": 0
  }
}
```

How do I, at every interval, only send updated properties from the all entities, and if all the entity didn't change, only send `true`?

Received entities should look like this:

```
{
  "0": true,
  "1": {
    "health": 99,
    "position": {
      "x": 1245, /** position and health changed, send them **/
      "y": 1866 /** even if only the x changed, send y too **/
    }
  },
  "2": true /** all the entity stayed the same, so send `true` **/
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem? Save the entities and check them before every send? Have you tried that?

Comment: I don't really know I could do it, I tried a lot of things, but none worked...

Comment: But what have you actually tried so far?

Comment: deep-diff, and things like that, but it removes y from position even if i wanna send it, and also some other things

Comment: Why use **deep** diff then? Use a normal diff. Or just check it by hand.

Comment: how to use normal diff or check by hand?